# Transparent issue with model in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d-model, objloader

I've been posting a lot on stackoverflow and other places trying to learn three js. This is my first project and using it as an experiment. I've successfully loaded an OBJ and MTL file. I have a problem where parts of the 3d model is transparent. [image: model]

You can notice the transparency on the tongue of the shoe, as well as other places. I tried uploading the model with the same texture files to http://www.3dvieweronline.com/ and it renders perfectly!

Here is my code:

```
(function() {

var scene, camera, renderer;
var geometry, material, mesh, sneaker;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
        HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

        var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x444444 );
                scene.add( ambient );

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 3, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 1, 20000 );
    camera.position.z = 1000;



    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
      var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
          HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
      renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
      camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    });

    geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true } );

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );


    // prepare loader and load the model
    var oLoader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
    oLoader.load('models/sneaker.obj', 'models/sneaker.mtl', function(object) {

      object.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
      object.rotation.y = 600;
      object.rotation.z= 600;
      sneaker = object;
      scene.add(sneaker);
    });






    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( WIDTH, HEIGHT );

    renderer.setClearColor(0x333F47, 1);

    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
    light.position.set(-100,200,100);
    scene.add(light);

    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;
    sneaker.rotation.x += 0.01;
    sneaker.rotation.y += 0.02;


    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}

})();
```

Please help.

Comment: Does it work if you add `side: THREE.DoubleSide` to you material?

Comment: @gaitat Would I place that in the oLoader block?

Comment: no in your `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial` definition.

Comment: @gaitat That mesh is just for a simple cube.

Comment: ok put it on the material of you show model

Comment: In objectloader block. When the object was loaded, it should have materials property. Materials is kinda collection of materials as gaitat said. Set `side: THREE.DoubleSide` for each. Here is an example code


`object.materials.forEach( function ( mat ) {
  mat.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
} );`

Answer (score 0):

Split the mesh into two meshes, one with the non transparent parts and one with them...
Disable depth sorting on the three.js renderer...
Make sure the solid mesh has a non-transparent material applied, and the transparent parts have a transparent material. Disable depth write on the transparent material as well.

Add the solid mesh first, then add the transparent mesh.

The problem you are having is that z-sorting and transparency are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
  object.traverse(child => {
    if (child.isMesh) child.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide
  })
```